# google adsense api CUSTOM_CHANNEL_ID issues

Tags: api, adsense

trying to get adSense customChannel report when 
i comment "'CUSTOM_CHANNEL_ID == XXXXXXXXX'" this is work perfect
and shown to me all report but when make it available again  not showing any thing my custom channel in google AdSense dashboard show me reports i trying to figure out what wrong in my code and thank you for helping

---

```
public  function reports($service, $accountId, $adClientId,$adsense) 
{
 $startDate = '2015-10-01';
 $endDate = 'today';
 $optParams = array(
            'metric' => array('PAGE_VIEWS', 
                               'CLICKS',
                               'COST_PER_CLICK', 
                                'EARNINGS'
                             ),
             'dimension' => 'DATE',
             'sort' => '-DATE',
             'filter' => array(
             'CUSTOM_CHANNEL_ID==XXXXXXXXX'
  ),

  );
   $report = $service->accounts_reports->generate($accountId,$startDate,$endDate, $optParams);

 return $report;
```

}

Answer (score 0):

The error was in 
    'CUSTOM_CHANNEL_ID==XXXXXXXXX'

```
you have to add ca-pub-(XXXXXXXX)clientid:(xxxxxx) channelid
```

example

```
'CUSTOM_CHANNEL_ID==ca-pub-XXXXXXXXX:XXXXXX'
```